# merging two files

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have two files (tab delimited) one file is has 4 columns and n number of rows and second file has 2 columns and n number of rows.

column 4 of first file is identical to column 2 of second file.

I want to have a third file which contains first four columns from file 1 and column 5 from file 2.

Any suggestions for one line bash script.

Comment: add the input to question as well as the expected output

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try with `join`

`join FILE1 FILE2 -1 4 -2 2 -t"tab"`

to express a join between the files FILE1 and FILE2 based on the 4th field (`-1 4`) of FILE1 and the 2nd field (`-2 2`) of FILE2

Comment: I want to get them as tab delimited (and I am not getting them as tab delimited).... any suggestions..

Comment: @Angelo : specify the field delimiter with the `t"tab"` option (as shown by an example here : http://compute.cnr.berkeley.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?join)

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the `join` command, see guide [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/lesser-known-linux-commands-join-paste-and-sort/5031653)

Answer (score 1):

For tabulator try

```
join -t \t files1 …
```