# Replacing strings in one file with strings from second file

Tags: string, bash, search, replace

I've been searching for a couple of days but I haven't got the right answer

I have two files that look like this:

File1:

```
>contig-100_23331 length_200 read_count_4043 
TCAG...
>contig-100_23332 length_200 read_count_4508 
TTCA...
>contig-100_23333 length_200 read_count_184 
TTCC...
```

File2:

```
>contig-100_23331_Cov:_30.9135
>contig-100_23332_Cov:_125.591
>contig-100_23333_Cov:_5.97537
```

I want to replace the lines with the names (>contig... length...) in File1 with the lines with the names in File2. Note that File2 contains only the contig names (no sequence).

I suppose theres a way with `sed`, but I can't find the solution

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [FAQ] soon.  Roughly how many lines will there be in File2 (tens or hundreds, thousands, millions, more)?  Presumably, the intent is to replace `contig-100_23331` with `contig-100_23331_Cov:_30.9135`, etc.

Comment: File2 has 23335 lines.

Comment: Indeed, I need to replace contig-100_23331 with contig-100_23331_Cov:_30.9135, and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is to use `sed` to create a `sed`-script from `File2` that is then used on `File1`:

```
sed 's/^\(>contig-[0-9]*_[0-9]*\)_.*/s%^\1 %& %/' File2 > sed.script
sed -f sed.script File1 > File.Out
rm -f sed.script
```

For the sample `File2`, the `sed.script` would contain:

```
s%^>contig-100_23331 %>contig-100_23331_Cov:_30.9135 %
s%^>contig-100_23332 %>contig-100_23332_Cov:_125.591 %
s%^>contig-100_23333 %>contig-100_23333_Cov:_5.97537 %
```

For the sample `File1`, the output of the `sed` processing would be:

```
>contig-100_23331_Cov:_30.9135 length_200 read_count_4043 
TCAG...
>contig-100_23332_Cov:_125.591 length_200 read_count_4508 
TTCA...
>contig-100_23333_Cov:_5.97537 length_200 read_count_184 
TTCC...
```

Some versions of `sed` may have problems with 23k lines in the `sed` script.  If that's a problem for you, then you can generate the `sed.script` and then split it ([`split`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/split.html)) into smaller chunks (e.g. 1000 lines each) and then run `sed -f chunk` for each of the chunks.  That's painful, but necessary.  Historically, HP-UX (archaic versions, like HP-UX 9 or 10) had rather limited versions of `sed` that could only handle a few hundred commands in the `sed` script.

Given that you're using `bash`, you can avoid the explicit intermediate file with [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution):

```
sed -f <(sed 's/^\(>contig-[0-9]*_[0-9]*\)_.*/s%^\1 %& %/' File2) File1 > File.Out
```

However, you should validate the script before using that notation.

Comment: Thank you so much Jonathan! the last command did the work. It takes a while, but works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

DISCLAIMER: Never done this ...

You might want to use the join command to merge the files [merging files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6408635/merging-two-files)

You may have to produce an intermediary file or stream for FILE2 which has an extra empty line so that two lines match in both files.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, `join` is unlikely to be the solution.  The data lines (`TCAG...`) would not be handled at all easily with `join`, and the data files must be in sorted order.